# Drag and drop with border and no overlaying divs

Tags: html, css, angular, angular-cdk-drag-drop

I want to have some draggable divs in a border, but I cannot make the elements not overlaying.
I am trying to use the not() selector of the CSS, but it does not work.
Here is my code.

```html
<div class="example-boundary">
  <div
    class="example-box"
    cdkDragBoundary=".example-boundary:not(.example-box)"
    cdkDrag
  >
    Item 1
  </div>
  <div class="example-box" cdkDragBoundary=".example-boundary" cdkDrag>
    Item 2
  </div>
</div>
```

Any suggestions? Thank you for your time!

Comment: `cdkDragBoundary` accepts a selector that targets an element, not an area. `.example-boundary:not(.example-box)` is trying to define an area. Did you try using `cdkDropList` ?

Comment: No, cdkDropList will put one item down/up to the other one, and I do not want that in my project.

Comment: Well, the only solution that comes to mind is to use `constrainPosition` property.  It accepts a method that manually determines where the element can be dragged. And then you can use `document.elementFromPosition` to see if there are any other elements in the position and decide. Here is the [example](https://github.com/angular/components/blob/8eb494e975bb75e52c9c81ad68d3d4b993546dfe/src/dev-app/drag-drop/drag-drop-demo.ts)